# Deleted Docker Image, How to Create New from Container?

Tags: docker

I've accidentally deleted all docker images on my machine with `docker rmi <imgid> -f` but fortunately had container intact. When i try to create image from container using `docker commit 575985d354ef ubuntu_16_10:dsktop` it gives following error:

`Error response from daemon: open /var/lib/docker/image/overlay2/imagedb/content/sha256/f31173ea77a68f70d897dba7623010a0471fa566a106c24a0e616278d37482e9: no such file or directory`

**How to create a new image from containers present ?**

Comment: Your command is correct. It seems that you have broken something

Comment: Are you trying to recover data from your container or are you actually trying to create a new image? The former may be possible. Please let me know what your goal is

Comment: I want to create fresh image from this container, everything else **(docker image from which container is created and private local repository**) is deleted that's why this error

Comment: Can't you just rebuild it, as you did the first time?

Comment: Nope, it took me 2-3 months to type commands into shell then commit this image into local repo (**which is gone for now**)

Comment: If you are crafting images buy committing changes from containers -- you are doing it wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be able to delete the image used by a running container:

```
$ docker run --name nginx-test -d nginx
351eb0e3a96b4375176358581a0afb460f57775382928860af764eb9d5e33b25

$ docker image rm nginx
Error response from daemon: conflict: unable to remove repository reference "nginx" (must force) - container 351eb0e3a96b is using its referenced image 5e69fe4b3c31
```

So if you managed to delete the image, you've also broken the container since docker uses a layered filesystem, reusing the image layers under the containers RW layer. That's the technical way of saying the image layers are not copied for each container.

You'll need to rebuild your image. Now would be a good time to consider using a Dockerfile instead of creating containers by hand and committing the results.

Comment: You're right but I am looking for some hack or solution. I have access to base image from where container is updated but won't have the commands used.

Comment: If you deleted the image, then the data is gone. The reason people use Dockerfiles is to make rebuilding images easier, avoiding this very issue.